# Why does this "grep -P" not do what I expect?

Tags: regex, grep, gnu

```
$ cat file
Here's a line.

This line has one blank line above it.


This line has two blank lines above it.



This line has three blank lines above it.




This line has four blank lines above it.
```

I want to find all lines in a text file that are preceded by two or more blank lines.  The command that I believe *should* do this instead finds only lines with exactly two preceding blank lines:

```
$ grep -Pzo '(?<=\n\n\n).*' file 
This line has two blank lines above it.
```

The grep man page (for GNU grep 2.21) does tag the -P option as "highly experimental", but claims the main issue is unimplemented behavior, about which it will warn.  But this appears, at first glance, to be buggy behavior: I can't really explain why what appears *before* the look-behind portion of the regular expression would affect whether the expression matches.  Am I overlooking some subtlety here?

I've found other ways to accomplish what I want, so I don't really need any advice on that.  However, this grep command is the most elegant solution (aside from the minor inconvenience of it not working), and I'd like to understand why it fails, and whether it can be tweaked to succeed.  Thanks.

Comment: GNU grep 2.16 behaves as expected and returns three lines. So it's indeed something fishy. Perhaps some unprintable chars ? What about `cat -A file` ? Grep 2.21 also works correctly in my case.

Comment: file may contain carraige return chars `\r`

Comment: @tvm: Weird.  The file has only printable characters (I just threw it together to demonstrate a problem I had observed on other files) and no spaces other than the visible ones between words.  My `grep` was aliased to `grep --colour=auto --directories=skip`, but removing the alias gives me the same results I was seeing before.  Switching from bash to sh (the only other shell on my system) does not change the output.  What else might be causing us to see different results?

Comment: @AvinashRaj: no `\r`s.  I created the file in vi on a Linux system.

Comment: I've tried three shells, two `grep` versions against your file example and command and it works. Since your system has latest `grep`, chances are that it also uses brand new `libpcre` library (which was updated in 2015). I would suspect that difference between the outputs is caused by something fishy in the PCRE lib.

Comment: @tvm: `pcretest -C` shows `PCRE version 8.35 2014-04-04`.  I'll try upgrading that to the latest version and see what happens.  Thanks!

Comment: @Targeloid Well, I have 8.31 and it works. So, that's probably not the cause either.

Comment: `PCRE version 8.36 2014-09-26` fails in the same manner.  So it may be a libpcre bug introduced between 8.31 and 8.35.  Can anyone using 8.35 or 8.36 confirm they see the same results I do?

Comment: I apologize, I'm not sure what I've did wrong at beginning, but `grep 2.21` apparently didn't work (I must have executed it without slash dot and triggered the original `grep` instead).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some investigation and mangling with PCRE libs, I've actually found out that this incorrect behaviour is caused by `grep` itself.

`grep` 2.21 seems to be the first version that doesn't works right, eg.:

```
➜  ~  grep-2.21/src/grep -Pzo '(?<=\n\n\n).*' ~/file 
This line has two blank lines above it.

➜  ~  grep-2.20/src/grep -Pzo '(?<=\n\n\n).*' ~/file
This line has two blank lines above it.
This line has three blank lines above it.
This line has four blank lines above it.
```

Quite a bit of changes were introduced since 2.20 according to `grep` ([git repository](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/log)).

To conclude, It is a bug and should be reported.

Comment: Thank you for digging deeper and figuring out what was happening!  Your first comment to my original question indicated that this worked for you in grep 2.21.  What did you have to change on your system to invoke the 2.21 bug?  This will be important in the bug report.

Comment: I explained that in the last comment. I think I've mistakenly executed the built-in `grep` instead of 2.21.

Comment: Whoops, the user interface was hiding that comment, and I thought I'd read them all so didn't click "show more."  Anyway, I reported the bug (http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=20957) and it's been fixed now.  Thanks again!